# Bitshifting long int returns wrong data

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, long-integer, bit-shift, unsigned

I'm trying to return two 32 bit int values (_mouseX and _mouseY) from a function by packing them into a 64 bit value first, then unpacking them elsewhere in the code when I use them. However, the data is completely incorrect when I get it through this function. I already confirmed that the original _mouseX and _mouseY data and the SetOrientation functions are fine; the problem is somewhere in the bitshifting or maybe casting or teh types Im using in this GetMouseXY function. Could you please have a look? Thanks.

```
long int Input::GetMouseXY()
{
    return (_mouseX << 32) |_mouseY;
}

long int mouseY = pInput->GetMouseXY() & 0xFFFFFFFF;
long int mouseX = (pInput->GetMouseXY() >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
_CamPosition->SetOrientation(XMFLOAT3((float)mouseY, (float)mouseX, 0.f));
```

Comment: Shifting a 32-bit value 32 positions is undefined. You have to make it 64 bits *first*.

Comment: The compiler should have warned you about the mistake. Did you read the compiler warnings? If ever the compiler is mute, raise warning level (like g++ -Wall etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Use `(long int)_mouseX<<32|_mouseY`, because you need to cast to a 64-bit type before shifting by 32.

Two notes: First, use `std::uint64_t`, if you need a 64-bit type. Second: why don't you use a struct for this? Like

```
struct MouseCoord {
    uint32_t x, y;
};

MouseCoord Input::GetMouseXY();
```

It's much more clear to see, what's going on.

Comment: I just wanted to do it elegantly in fewer lines. Also I felt like it would cause more clutter (possible performance cost too?) having to declare a new struct and make it accessible to both of the classes that are using it.

Comment: @Dude: I don't think it's elegant. Usually, such GUI codebases contain a 2D point struct, so you don't have to define one just for this. Or, you can just use `std::array<uint32_t, 2>`, if you don't want to define a new struct. I don't think that performance matters too much in a mouse coordinate accessor function. In 64-bit codes, a 64-bit struct returned in a register, just like a 64-bit number, so performance will be the same.

Comment: @Dude: Beware, left shifting signed int is not so well defined. And long int is only 32bits on LLP64 platforms (WIN64). It does not make code more elegant, just less portable.